# Why does changing a hostname in the hosts file not change my computer name?

Tags: windows, powershell, localhost, hostname

I have to run some servers with different names. So I changed the hostname in Windows 10 inside `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`. I changed the name from `localhost` to `brandcil.local`:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       brandcil.local
#   ::1             brandcil.local
```

Now when I am running `nslookup 127.0.0.1` in powershell terminal, it is showing this:

```
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.43.1

Name:    localhost
Address:  127.0.0.1
```

I restarted my machine but it does not take effect. How do I change the hostname then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the `hosts` file will not change the hostname. It is only used for hostname-IP-resolution. Besides that, each line that begins with `#` is a comment and not an active configuration. You can rename a computer with the following PowerShell cmdlet:

```bsh
Rename-Computer -NewName brandcil -Restart
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using windows after a long ago

Answer (score 2):

First of all, any line in the hosts file that begins with `#` is a comment and will be ignored. The file itself tells you this if you read it. Second, the hosts file has nothing to do with your computer's hostname. All you're doing is creating aliases that will only work on the machines you modify the hosts file on. You're not changing the hostname at all. Third, localhost -> 127.0.0.1 is a static mapping no longer controlled by the hosts file so it will always map to 127.0.0.1. Again, the hosts file tells you this if you read it.

To rename your computer go into Settings --> System --> About. There's a "Rename this PC" button.

If you don't want to use that, then I recommend using the `Rename-Computer` Powershell command.